# Problem rendering fetched data with reactjs and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to fetch data that contains a JSON array that looks like this

```
[
   {
     "prof": "Jason Crank",
     "views": "2",
     //etc etc
   }
]
```

and I'm trying to transform the JSON object into an JavaScript array I can map and render the appropriate amount of blocks, I'm using typescript and this is my code

```js
const [notesArr, setNotesArr] = useState<notesInterface[]>([])

const fetchNotes = async (active) => {
    try{
        const response = await fetch("my server", {
            method:"GET",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
        .then(resp => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp)))
        .then(result => setNotesArr(result))
        

        return(
            <div>
                {notesArr.map((notes) => <NoteThumb link={notes.link} title={notes.title} semester={notes.semester} prof={notes.prof} timestamp={notes.timestamp} likes={notes.likes} views={notes.views} pages={notes.pages} isBookmarked={notes.isBookmarked}/>)}
            </div>
        )

    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

and the interface I'm using looks like this

```
interface notesInterface {
    prof: string
    views: number
}
```

When trying this I get an error that says `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I'd appreciate any help and I can offer more snippets of my code if necessary

Comment: Move your `return (...)` **out** of the `fetchNotes` function. Where do you call `fetchNotes` anyway?

Comment: @Phil I call it in the return of the function component

Comment: @Phil its a function inside a react function component

Comment: Can you post your `<NoteThumb />` component?

Comment: its not really required all it does is takes strings

Comment: In order to fetch data, you should use useEffect hook and call there your function fetchNotes, and remove rendering in your function, it must be in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise what you're being told in the comments above...

1. Your functional component needs to return the JSX node, not your `fetchNotes` function
2. Use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to execute `fetchNotes` on component mount

```
const Notes: React.FC = () => {
  const [notesArr, setNotesArr] = useState<notesInterface[]>([])

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("my server")
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${await response.text()}`)
      }
      setNotesArr(await response.json())
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      {notesArr.map(note => <NoteThumb {...note} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I cleaned up your `fetch()` call as well; `GET` is the default *method* and `GET` requests do not have `Content-type` due to there being no request body.